# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ always a quadratic field when $d$ is a squarefree integer?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ always a quadratic field when $d$ is a squarefree integer?

This is the converse of a theorem about quadratic fields, is it true?

Comment: No, if $d = 1$, it is just $\mathbb{Q}$ (if this didn't answer your question, please be more specific about what d is)

Comment: @Countable I'm assuming $d$ is squarefree as in the title.

Comment: From Wikipedia... The map $d ↦ \mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$ is a bijection from the set of all square-free integers d ≠ 0,1 to the set of all quadratic fields.

Comment: From wolfram: "The number 1 is by convention taken to be squarefree"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $1$ is the smallest [square free integer.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer)

So Your argument is false. But other than $d=1$, your argument is true. Indeed, If $d≠ 1  $ square free integer, then $d=p_1p_2...p_n$, and $\sqrt{d}=\sqrt{p_1p_2...p_n}.$